# Adding Category to Child Posts Permalink

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I'm attempting to add a category of each child post to that post's permalink. The post type is called `lessons`. I have a taxonomy called `Child Categories` that contains the terms `workbooks` and `workbook-solutions`

I would like to make it so that if a post is a child of another post and contains either of the terms it is written as the following.

lessons/this-is-a-parent-post/**workbooks**/this-is-a-child-post
lessons/this-is-a-parent-post/**workbook-solutions**/this-is-a-child-post

This is the code I've written so far, but it hasn't resulted in the links rewriting.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomy_to_child_post_url' );
function add_taxonomy_to_child_post_url() {  
global $post;
if ( has_term( 'workbooks', $post ) && $post->post_parent ) {
            add_rewrite_rule(
                        '^lessons/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
                        'index.php?post_type=lessons&child-categories=$matches[1]&name=$matches[3]',
                        'top'
                    );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: your questions code adds a filter to the post type link that uses the `wpd_post_link` function, but it's missing from your question. `init` is not a filter, you can't return strings, did you mix up `init` with `post_type_link`?

Comment: @TomJNowell You are correct. That was a typo on my part. It has been fixed in my post. I tested it on the site and it is still not rewriting.

Comment: Where is the $id parameter in get_post coming from? Make sure where ever that variable is you have it within the scope of this code! That may be why its not working?

Comment: @YOUGLE I've added $id = get_the_ID(); This should pull the post ID number in the current post. This does not result in a rewrite.

Comment: Just revised the code so it is more simplified.

Comment: I see your updates and it is even more confusing, your `add_taxonomy_to_child_post_url` function is pulling `$post` out of nothing, and `init` is a very weird and incorrect hook to do this kind of work on ( WP doesn't know which post yet, the main query hasn't happened yet ). You also can't add rewrites conditionally like that inside `if` statements